# Column wrap using JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

Is it possible, using *JasperReports* (with or without *DynamicJasper*), to dynamically wrap columns to the next page if there are too many to fit one page?

Here is an example of what I mean here:

[image]

Context information:

I am going *Java* for redesigning a project and, for different reasons, I have to use *JasperReports*. Actually, it is done very manually by "drawing" on a 2d surface for each page, controlling manually when we break, hence introducing that kind of wrapping feature myself. I am using a native DLL (Windows only) as my application is actually native/.NET. There are .NET replacements, but I need to do *Java* for this.